# Finding the missing value in the cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have this two examples of the cumulative distribution function and I have to find the missing variable $k$.

Example 1:
$$
F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \ x \le1 \\\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+kx & 1<x<2 \\1 & 2 \le x \end{cases}
$$
I think here we have to equate $\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+kx$ with $1$, but I do not know with what to replace $x$ so I can get $k$.

Example 2:
$$
F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0 &x<0 \\\frac{1}{2}x &0\leq x\leq 1 \\1-k(x-4)^{2} &1\leq x\leq 4\\1 &x>4\end{cases}
$$
With example 2 I am not sure which one should I equate with $1$.

I would appreciate help solving these two examples.

Comment: In the first, it should be $F_X(x) = 1$ at $x = 2$ and $F_X(x) = 0$ at $x = 1$

Answer (score 1):

$F$ is only right-continuous (not necessarily left-continuous), so you should only equate with the value at the right.

$F(2-)=F(2)$, so $\left.\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+kx\right|_{x=2}=1$

and for the second example:

$F(1-)=F(1)$, so $=\left.\frac{1}{2}x\right|_{x=1}=\left.1-k(x-4)^{2}\right|_{x=1}$

Note that $F(4-)=F(4)=1$, so the right-continuity condition in $x=4$ is of no help in finding $k$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i calculated and got k=-1/2 for example 1 and k=0 for example 2. Is this correct?

Comment: I get $k=\frac{1}{18}$ for the second example.